# Using Gluon mobile with Netbeans 11.1

Tags: netbeans, gluon, gluon-mobile, netbeans-11

Just a really basic question. Have I got the feeling that the plugin has not been updated thin the 8.2, am I Wrong ?

Even with a manual [download](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/57602) of this version, I can't install it (gradle issue even if gradle is already installed..)

Comment: Yes, Gluon IDE plugins are still for Java 1.8, and for now, it is better to use them from NetBeans 8.2. That is going to change really soon, though, as support for JavaFX 13 is coming: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples

Comment: @JoséPereda When? Still using Java 8.